# How can a C# datatable be easily converted to a Deedle dataframe?

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

Ideally, I'd like to convert a C# datatable into a Deedle dataframe.

Comment: Without even knowing anything about the Deedle API, I did some research, and you can read from an `IDataReader`... which you can get a datareader from a datatable using `table.CreateDataReader()`, so try `var frame = Frame.ReadReader(table.CreateDataReader())` or some such.